# Cannot add script to a GameObject as a component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: VS screengrab]

This is my full script

I get an error on line 15, beginning at the "PlayerControls" word.

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PlayerControls' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace puggy
{
    public class InputHandler : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float horizontal;
        public float vertical;
        public float moveAmount;
        public float mouseX;
        public float mouseY;

        PlayerControls inputActions;

        Vector2 movementInput;
        Vector2 cameraInput;

        public void OnEnable()
        {
            if (inputActions == null)
            {
                inputActions = new PlayerControls();
                inputActions.PlayerMovement.Movement.performed += inputActions => movementInput = inputActions.ReadValue<Vector2>();
                inputActions.PlayerMovement.Camera.performed += i => cameraInput = i.ReadValue<Vector2>();
            }

            inputActions.Enable();

        }

        private void OnDisable()
        {
            inputActions.Disable();
        }

        public void TickInput(float delta)
        {
            MoveInput(delta);
        }

        private void MoveInput(float delta)
        {
            horizontal = movementInput.x;
            vertical = movementInput.y;
            moveAmount = Mathf.Clamp01(Mathf.Abs(horizontal) + Mathf.Abs(vertical));
            mouseX = cameraInput.x;
            mouseY = cameraInput.y;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm guessing it wants a reference for "PlayerControls". I'm confused though because I followed a walkthrough, I ran into other issues but was able to resolve them pretty quickly. This one is tripping me up though.

[image]

I'm expecting to be able to attach this script to my player model and have it move based on player input.

I have re-typed my script and followed other forums to see if anyone else has had similar issues.

EDIT:

[image: PlayerControls]

Comment: I assume `InputHandler.cs` is throwing errors because `PlayerControls.cs` contains errors or does not exist. Please show/add `PlayerControls.cs`

Comment: I updated with the PlayerControls.cs showing, and the text thats in the document

Comment: The PlayerControls.cs generated from me making an Action Map.

Comment: Player controls seems to contain a blank input handler and not a class called player controls as per the name

Comment: There’s no real “one answer” here. But, one of the first issues is that you have an InputHandler in the global namespace, and one in the “puggy” namespace. Then you’ve got a file name called PlayerInput, but the class name inside that file is InputHandler again. There’s a mishmash of file and class names, and namespaces.

Comment: Check inside you "PlayerControls" script if it has a namespace like you have inside your "InputHandler" (namespace puggy). If it does have a namespace then you should include it in your "InputHandler" like this (using namespace name).

Answer (score 0):

`public class PlayerControls` has to be in a file called **PlayerControls.cs**!

Looking at your [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLPal.jpg) you have **InputHandler** in a file called **PlayerControls.cs**

I guess you copied/renamed the class or file. Please make sure Filename and Classname match!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. When making the "PlayerControls Input Action" I forgot to also click "generate C# class".

This makes sure that all the stuff I set up in the GUI, is applied into the C# script.